# How to determine what GUI library a program is using?

Tags: gui, i3, gtk

For example, I need to know what GUI library Synergy uses so I can configure the correct config files (such as `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` for GTK3 programs). How would this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

With `ldd` (`man ldd`):

```
ldd $(type -p synergy)
```